# parse tableview controller added to parent view will not select cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a view controller, and when pressing a button I want it to display a tableview on top of the view controller.  I have used the following code for my view controller:

```
    @IBAction func addRecipientsButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller:contactTableView =         self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("contactTableView") as! contactTableView
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,100,300,400)
    controller.view.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    self.addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```

And here is the code for my table view controller:

```
    import Foundation
    import Parse
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class contactTableView: PFQueryTableViewController {
@IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var RecipientArray: Array <String> = []
  var avatarView: AvatarView!
var error: NSError?
var lastSelection: NSIndexPath!

enum Error: ErrorType {
    case failed
    case Short
}

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)


    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Contact"
    self.textKey = "UserID"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Contact")
    query.whereKey("UserID", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.includeKey("ContactID")
    return query
}


//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) ->
    crewViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! crewViewCell!
        //if cell == nil {
        //    cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        //}

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)



        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        let object2 = object["ContactID"] as! PFObject
        object2.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        }
        let picquery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        picquery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: object2["UserID"]!)
        picquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let imagesobjects = objects as! [PFObject]

                for object : PFObject in objects as! [PFObject] {
                    let image = object["UserPic"] as! PFFile?

                    image?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

                                self.avatarView = AvatarView(image: image!)
                                self.avatarView.center = CGPointMake(40, 35)
                                self.avatarView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)
                                cell.addSubview(self.avatarView)

       // cell.contactPic?.image = image
        cell.nameLabel?.text = object2["FirstName"] as! String
        cell.nameLabel?.textColor = self.getRandomColor()
        cell.jobLabel?.text = object2["LastName"] as! String
        cell.jobLabel?.textColor = self.getRandomColor()


                                                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
        return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! crewViewCell!
         let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        //let currentObject = objects?[row] as! PFObject

        let obj: PFObject! = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if selectedCell.accessoryType == .None {
            let object2 = obj["ContactID"] as! PFObject
            object2.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



            var RecipientString: String = object2["UserID"]! as! String
            self.RecipientArray.append(RecipientString as String)
            print(obj["ContactID"])

            let entityDescription =
            NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Recipients",
                inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

            let recipient = Recipients(entity: entityDescription!,
                insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            recipient.recipient = RecipientString
            print("Recipient Saved")

            recipient.rownumber = indexPath.row as Int

            do{
                try! self.managedObjectContext?.save()
            } catch {

            }
            selectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

            }
        }else {
            let object2 = obj["ContactID"] as! PFObject
            object2.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       // if selectedCell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            var RecipientString: String = object2["UserID"]! as! String
            let i = self.RecipientArray.indexOf(RecipientString)
            self.RecipientArray.removeAtIndex(i!)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipients")
            fetchRequest.includesSubentities = false
            fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"recipient == %@", RecipientString)
            var items = []
            var error: NSError?
            let moc = self.managedObjectContext
            // moc is your NSManagedObjectContext here
            try! items = moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

            for recipient in items {
                moc!.deleteObject(recipient as! NSManagedObject)
                print("Recipient Deleted")
            }

            try! self.managedObjectContext?.save()
            selectedCell.accessoryType = .None
        }

    }

        }
}






func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{
    let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}



    }
```

When I run this, the table displays how it should, and I can close the table again and use my initial view control.  But I cannot select any table cells.  The table has the data source and delegate setup as it should do to the 'contactTableView' file.  And if I link a modal segue to the table rather than systematically calling it, I can select the cells and this works how it should do.

But currently I would like to systematically call this on top of my current view and be able to select cells.

If anybody has any pointers on what I have missed I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before and it is a bit annoying. This usually works for me though:

```
self.contactTableView.canCancelContentTouches = false
self.contactTableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```